# Control binding for aura attribute being passed from parent to child

Tags: aura, aura-attribute, lightninginput, databinding

I am taking record id and object name as input from user

```
    <aura:attribute name="recordidinput" type="Id" />
    <aura:attribute name="objectname" type="String" />
    
    <lightning:input name="objectdetail" label="Object" value="{!v.objectname }" placeholder="enter the object..."/>
    <lightning:input name="recordiddetail" label="Record ID" value="{!v.recordidinput }"
placeholder="enter the recordId..."/>
    <lightning:button variant="brand" label="Submit" title="Submit" onclick="{!c.handleSubmit}" />
```

These attributes have to be passed on to a child component as follows :

```
    <c:displayRecordDetailsLWC recordIdDetail="{!v.recordidinput}" objectName="{!v.objectname}">
```

The problem is that :

The value should get passed to child component only when submit button is pressed. Right now, the button is useless and due to two-way binding the values are getting updated at every keystroke which is not what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't bind the value, but assign it when you want to update the child object:

```
<lightning:input aura:id="objectdetail" label="Object" placeholder="enter the object..."/>
<lightning:input aura:id="recordiddetail" label="Record ID" />
```

...

```
handleSubmit: function(component, event, helper) {
  let objectdetail = component.find("objectdetail").get("v.value");
  let recordiddetail = component.find("recordiddetail").get("v.value");
  component.set("v.objectname", objectdetail);
  component.set("v.recordidinput", recordiddetail);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I wanted to ask if there are any resources that you can suggest to learn how to play around with attributes and methods like this?

Comment: @ShreyaPandita There's no "one place" for things like this. A lot of things are possible. setTimeout is a common Aura example, mentioned [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_cb_mod_ext_js.htm) in the docs, and you can find other examples out there on the Internet (e.g. doing an API call, loading a file, and other asynchronous tasks). And, of course, feel free to turn here, we love coming up with solutions that aren't in the books.

Comment: And wherever possible, use an LWC component. Despite binding being slightly more complex to implement, just about everything else is easier / faster (especially calls to the server).

Comment: @CasparHarmer Also a good point. LWC has one-way binding, so doing it as in this answer is the natural mode for LWC.

Comment: Nice, I did not know LWC has one-way binding! Will check it out next time My use-case was that I had to call two child components (one aura and one lwc). I used aura as a parent component because I read somewhere we cannot call aura child component from lwc.